# Anychart X-Axis Data Overflow

Tags: android, anychart

Anyone know how to deal with a situation where you have too much data to fit onto the screen in a line chart on mobile?

When I have 20 observations in a time series on the X-axis, everything is OK. When I have 100, the data starts to write over itself.

Do I need to sample the data myself or is there a function in AnyChart for tick sampling?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reduce the number of ticks on the X-Axis you can add the following line to your code:
`chart.xScale().ticks().interval(4);`
It makes the chart to show a tick for every 4 points.
If I got your idea in the wrong way, please, provide more details about your issue.